# Using Handlerbars helpers in backbone.marionette.handlebars

Tags: templates, backbone.js, marionette, handlebars.js

I have a web application using [backbone.marionette](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette) with [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) templating provided via the extension [backbone.marionette.handlebars](https://github.com/asciidisco/Backbone.Marionette.Handlebars). This is working well but I want to now add some [templateHelpers](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html) to help with formatting and I can't seem to get it to work.

I have included template helpers in what I believe is the correct way (see below) but I get and error from require.js saying it "GET .../templates/helpers/foo.js 404 (NotFound)" as soon as the backbone.marionette application starts.

My template looks like this (UPDATED: Thanks Billy Chan)

```
<div>{{{foo myData}}}</div>
```

And I have tried two things. Firstly defining a simple helper inside my Marionette.ItemView as so:

```
...
return Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: template,
    templateHelpers: {
        foo: function (someData) { return 'foo and ' + someData; }
    },
...
```

This didn't work, i.e. I still got the require.js error given in the first paragraph. (Note: I did try without a function argument in case that was the problem but didn't fix it).

The second thing I did was add a simple file .../templates/helpers/foo.js with a require.js define returning an object with a function foo inside it. This gave the same error as before, i.e. missing file. That might be because I need to define this file as a dependency. I would prefer the first method which does not need an external file, but happy to use this method if that is the correct way.

Finally, I noticed [this issue](https://github.com/asciidisco/Backbone.Marionette.Handlebars/issues/6) on the backbone.marionette.handlebars github. This suggest that templateHelpers work, but might have a problem. Any suggestions on using helpers in this environment would be very much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I bit more experimenting shows that if I have {{foo}} or {{{foo}}} then it calls the foo function in Marionette.ItemView.extend but doesn't insert the return of foo. However if I have {{foo myData}} or {{{foo myData}}} then it gives the 404 Not found error listed above. Strange.

Just for completeness I am using

- backbone 1.0.0
- backbone.marionette 1.0.4
- backbone.marionette.handlebars 0.2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I took @BillyChan's suggestion and started digging into the code. Following the rabbit trail it turns out that another plugin was handling the helpers. The single page application, which I didn't design, uses a plugin called  [require-handlebars-plugin](https://github.com/SlexAxton/require-handlebars-plugin) to integrate handlebars into require.

This plugin knows nothing about Backbone.Marionette so it implements its own registerHelper's convention using require, which, you guessed it, expects the helper to be in .../templates/helpers/xxx.js in a specific format. This explains why I was getting my file 404, or even if the file was there it wasn't in the right format.

So thanks again for the comments, but my mistake as I was looking at the wrong documentation. I hadn't used helpers before so I thought I had set it up incorrectly, which I had, but not in the way that the Handlebars and Backbone.Marionette documentation I was looking at was suggesting. I am wiser now.